# How to find variables by value in eclipse debugger

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin

I love eclipse debugger, it's very useful and have many tricks, but there is a tool that I have even not found. I have already searched very much on google and nothing solved my problem.

I want to filter debug variables by it's value, It is useful when has many variables and I want show the only that satisfy an expression or contains an word.

Note that I don't want filter by variable's name.

Comment: Conditional breakpoints will help you. Check [this](http://www.eclipseonetips.com/2009/12/28/setup-eclipse-breakpoints-to-stop-only-under-certain-conditions/) and [this](http://eclipse.dzone.com/tips/effective-debugging) to know about conditional break point. Is that you looking for?

Comment: I know this problem... there is a list with hundrets of elements and you need to find one specific... I haven't found a way eclipse helps you here.

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK unfortunately this is not what I want, I'm looking for a way to filter variables in "variables view" by variables content. Conditional breakpoints will not help to filter all variables with specific value. And also, if I don't know the name of the variable (suppose that I know only the value) , conditional breakpoint will not be useful too.

Comment: variable may be primitive type or object type then how to decide value of object types like `Car` object?You can add watch point on the variables or custom expression on these variables.Don't understand the need of variable filtering?Can you elaborate on the need?

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK Ok, in my specific case,I'm debugging an application over JBOSS that contains many, many variables, including sessions variables and JBOSS's control variables. The process is part of login-config (service of JBOSS that authenticates users), and I want to understand better it's behavior. I want to locate an string inside JSP context, but I don't know the name of the variable because it is all of jboss uses. In short, I want this tool to understand better JBOSS work. Sorry if seems confuse, It's difficult to clearly explain.